# IE Incompatibility with form css styling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, forms, textarea

The source code is like this:

```
<div id="contact">
                <div class="form">
                    <form action="contact.php" method="post" name="contact-us">
                         <div class="right">
                            <div class="labeled">
                                <label for="text">body</label>
                            </div>
                            <textarea id="text" name="text" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is css block for textarea and related objects :

```
div.right {
float: right;
margin: 5px 0;
}

div.labeled {
width: 150px;
float: right;
}

div.right div.form textarea#text, textarea#text {
background: #A2A2A2;
border: 1px solid #811D1D;
height: 50px;
margin-right: 20px;
width: 220px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

in FF all things are correct but in IE the textarea hasn't been styled and remains Intact.
You can see difference in below image too :

[image: defference between IE and FF]

Also as you can see the label tag styled true in FF and remains intact in IE!
How could I fix these?

Regards...

Comment: Not all versions of IE do support this. Which version are you using? You did manage to get the scrollbar to the left, though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
There was just this css block on page's header :

```
div.form input[type="submit] {
padding: 2px;
background: #A2A2A2;
border: 1px solid #811D1D;
color: #000000;
height: 20px;
}
```

And As you see there is one lost quotation mark at **[type="submit"]**. IE couldn't correct code but other browsers do that! This was the problem

P.s: Special thanks to @Bakudan for introducing [jsfiddle Online Editor](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Not all versions of IE support the textarea styling.

In your code, the textarea is within the div that floats right. Seems like you're asking for odd behaviour. Better float the 'labeled' div (or rather remove that div and do some trickery on the label itself).

Comment: Do You mean I should use texearea naked and not inside DIVs?

Comment: Not necessarily, although you could. I meant you should float the 'labeled' div instead of the 'right' div. And to make that succeed, you should either put the textarea in a new div on its own, or you should add the style 'display: block' to the textarea to make it behave like a block element (which a div is).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/KzYgt/

`overflow: auto;` - for the scrollbar

Comment: Ha ha I've just realized that the textarea styled true when there are NOT any text type input on CSS. (Like: <input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="20" /> ). That's so hilarious!!

Answer (score 1):

Styling form elements is a serious hell since most of the controls are styled by OS and browser and those styles are hard to override, in some cases impossible. You should however be able to achieve the background color and scrollbar disappearing.

Are you certain there is no other element with the id "text" on your page?

A good overview of what's possible with css for textarea styling can be found here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/text-input-multiple/#ie6-xp

Comment: on the page there are also some input tags with type "text" but the text id is unique. Thanks I'll check your link